# flash upload image to drawing canvas

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

im trying to create a online business card editor to learn flash again, one of the functionality im trying to achieve is being able to upload an image (jpg,png etc) and place said image onto a drawing canvas and then being able to scale the image and rotate the image and move the image around. can some one direct me to a decent tutorial for this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to load the external image with Loader class:

http://blog.728media.com/2009/03/11/how-to-load-external-images-in-actionscript-30/

after that, in above code, you need to access the bitmapData of that image. It should be Bitmap(myLoader.content).bitmapData.

After that, you need to prepare your canvas code and then use something like this to scale the data from within your mouse listeners attached to your canvas...

http://userflex.wordpress.com/2008/09/04/scaling-bitmap-data/

So, first load an image you want to scale etc and then you can slowly start working on your canvas code...

mouse listeners info:

http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHNY_srRS374RS374&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=as3+mouse+listeners

See how this works out for you.